# TinyMCE edit input values and button text?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have this code inside the contents of my TinyMCE Editor:

```
<input value="value">
<button>Text</button>
```

But TinyMCE will not allow me to edit the Text of the button or the input value.  I also put together a minimal [example here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/uBeaab/3) in the TinyMCE fiddle.

How can I allow these values to be edited?

Comment: This looks to be a WebKit issue, as I can edit it in both Firefox and IE11, but not Chrome, Safari, or Opera..

Answer (score 3):

Here is fix for Chrome, in Opera sill not working, Safari not tested yet

> -webkit-user-select: inherit;

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/EBeaab/2

Comment: That's a start, but it seems very finicky.  Most of the time clicking the input does not give it text focus.  I'm still trying to find a pattern to it.  Safari and Opera support aren't very important in my case.

Comment: highlighting the text before clicking the input seems to work, and makes the whole thing much more tractable. This could make for a viable workaround, if you can highlight the input field when TinyMCE starts.

Comment: Thank you wasikuss and penguat.  I was able to use your recommendations to build a working example that allows editing both the input and button text:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2Ceaab/1